# Right way to postprocess a file after upload with a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, events, servlets, upload

I have written a JSP and a class that takes a file upload and stores it locally on the server. After saving the file, the uploaded file is to be processed. The required method calls should not be called statically for the file storage.

**Not** like this:

```
storefile (file);
MyPostprocessingManager pm = new MyPostprocessingManager(file);
pm.createThumbs();
pm.doFooBarWithTheFile();
```

This coupling is too tight.

The methods should be started on a kind of "event". So after uploading a file is an event fired and informed the appropriate classes who will carry out further processing.

The whole fails only on the fact that I do not know where and how I need to register the appropriate listener. In most instances this is already done in a main class. But I can not do so since I do not have a central starting point.

I am fully wrong track? Maybe one of you has another idea?

Thanks and greetings,
Ben

Comment: Do you want this done synchronously or not?

Comment: After the Upload the postprocessing must be start. The other steps will then pass in sequence.

Comment: What I mean is, is the postprocess part of the request handling?

Comment: No. This is a separate task.

Comment: I recommend you create some blocking queue that is visible from your `Servlet`. You would have some separate thread(s) that waits for elements in the queue. The elements are your events.

Comment: Is not it possible to fire an event when an upload is done? This event could not be offset by a corresponding postprocessing class?

Comment: Firing the event would be pushing it onto the blocking queue.

Comment: Can you give me an example that might explain this? Where should I include what classes? Thx.

Comment: I don't have an example. Create a `MyPostprocessingManager` and an `ExecutorService`. These don't have to be in the `Servlet`, but they have to be available to it (perhaps through `ServletContext`). When your request is finished, push the file/event to a `BlockingQueue` contained in the `MyPostprocessingManager`. Some other component running on a separate `Thread` will read from the `BlockingQueue` and execute the tasks with the `ExecutorService`. Check out the `ServletContextListener` interface for starting up these components.

Comment: What do you think about this approach?

After starting the Applicationserver a EventDispatcher is registered as an singleton. About this EventDispatcher the events will be distributed to the listener.

Comment: That sounds right. The listener (or consumer) has to be running on its own `Thread` otherwise execution will be synchronous.